# jQuery sortable animate list when removing an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I animate the re-shuffling of a jQuery sortable list when a child element is removed?

I've created a quick example of what i'm working with: http://jsfiddle.net/nxbtb/

**Code used to make the list sortable / remove items**

```
$("ul").sortable();
$("li").dblclick(function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

I would like the other elements to animate in to their new position. Is there a property or function of jQuery / jQuery UI which I can hook into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use animations before removing.

```
$("ul").sortable();
$("li").dblclick(function(){
    $(this).animate({width:"0"},500, function(){$(this).remove();});

});
```